# Cannot Access static field c# Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ssis-2012

I have the following c# code within a 2012 SSIS package Script Task using 4.5 Framework:

```
[Microsoft.sqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScripTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
Public partial class ScriptMain
{
     static ScriptMain()
     {
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomai_AssemblyResolveForDLL);
     }

      Static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolveForDLL(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
      {
            If (args.Name.Contains("NameofMydll"))
            {
                 string path = @"c:\Temp\";
                 return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "NameofMydll.dll"));
            }
      }
       return null;
  }
```

The purpose of this code is to load a .dll file used in a SSIS Script task  during run time.  The way the code works is just like what is described [here.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/)  With the path hard coded, it works fine.

The problem I have is I need to dynamically set the value of the path so I can promote the code from server to server with no hard coded values.  Since the function is static, I didn't know how to do it.

The line of code here:

```
  MyVariable = (string)Dts.Variables.["MyVariable"].value;
```

...receives the value with `MyVariable` declared as a global public string variable (this works fine as long as its not within the code above).   But using "MyVariable" in place of the `@"c:\Temp\"` is where I get the `Cannot access non static field`...error.

Changing the declaration to `public static string` allows it to compile, but throws an error at run time.

```
 Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation.
```

The value is assigned through a function just before the line of code below is called:

`AppDomain.CurentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolveForDLL)`

The call to the function is the first line of code in `Main()`, the line of code above is the 2nd.

All I need to do is assign the value of the path from a variable.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you assign the value to this static path variable?

Comment: @MinaJacob, see update.

Comment: can you narrow down the scope from global public string variable to as class static variable? I'm suspecting the static vars initialization order is causing this error

Comment: @MinaJacob, As a static variable, the line of code `Dts.Variables["MyVariable"].Value` errors at `Dts` with the error `Cannot access non static property Dts in static context

Answer (score 0):

Change to `MyVariable = (string)Dts.Variables.["MyVariable"].value;`

or access via it's position`MyVariable = (string)Dts.Variables.[0].value;`

Comment: I mentioned this in my question, it errors out saying it can't access it.  Its a static Function.

Comment: The example code is not valid and needs changing as per my answer.

Comment: I understand now, Yes you are correct the example code is wrong. But your code is how I actually have it my project. My example is updated now. Thank you for your post

Comment: @Jason R.
 Did you get the answer for this